# Hard-coded payment option types

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I noticed that the payment type (e.g. used in `http://{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/GetCartPaymentMethods(cartId='Cart01', paymentType='Creditcard'))` is no where configured in Sitecore. It turns out that it's hard-coded in the `BaseTranslateItemsToPaymentBlock`:

```
protected virtual string GetPaymentTemplateName(string paymentOptionType)
{
return paymentOptionType == "1" ? "CreditCard" : (paymentOptionType == "2" ? "LoyaltyCard" : (paymentOptionType == "3" ? "GiftCard" : (paymentOptionType == "4" ? "Federated" : string.Empty)));
}
```

I would expect a Sitecore configuration setting. This is difficult to use at the XC9 API, and Commerce Connect doesn't work well with it. At the moment I cannot retrieve all payment options and next retrieve the payment methods using the PaymentOptionType because that expects (at XC9 side) the above mentioned hard-coded values.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by overriding the base method;

```
public class TranslateItemsToPaymentMethodsBlock : Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.TranslateItemsToPaymentMethodsBlock
{
    public TranslateItemsToPaymentMethodsBlock(CommerceCommander commander) : base(commander)
    {
    }

    protected override string GetPaymentTemplateName(string paymentOptionType)
    {
          return paymentOptionType == "5" ? "MyCustomOptionType" : base.GetPaymentTemplateName(paymentOptionType);
    }
}
```

and configuring XC9 to use the new class:

```
.ConfigurePipeline<IGetPaymentOptionsPipeline>(d =>
{
   d.Replace<Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.TranslateItemsToPaymentOptionsBlock, TranslateItemsToPaymentOptionsBlock>();
})
```